# Using redis with bokeh-server. Permission denied: '/bokehpids.json'

Tags: redis, bokeh, supervisord

I'm trying to run bokeh-server with supervisor with redis as a backend and I get this error message on startup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/bin/bokeh-server", line 7, in <module>
    bokeh.server.run()
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 175, in run
    start_server(args)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 179, in start_server
    start.start_simple_server(args)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/start.py", line 54, in start_simple_server
    start_redis()
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/start.py", line 40, in start_redis
    save=redis_save)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/services.py", line 81, in start_redis
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/services.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.add_to_pidfile()
  File "/usr/share/nginx/test-status/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/services.py", line 46, in add_to_pidfile
    with open(self.pidfilename, "w+") as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/bokehpids.json'
```

Note that I can run the server with supervisor if I use memory as the backend, and I can run bokeh-server manually with redis as a backend just fine. Does anyone know where the permissions I should change lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was trying to access the pidfile in the root directory...

I solved this by changing the directory in the supervisor config file:

```
[program:bokeh]
...
    directory=/usr/share/nginx/test-status
...
```